# Dwellers aren't finding gears and weapons in Wasteland

Tags: fallout-shelter

I've sent level 20-30 dwellers with high stats to the Wasteland for a day and they don't find any weapons or gears. They still collect exp and caps but nothing else. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

It's pretty rare to find weapons in the wasteland. If you have a Mr. Handy that will do the trick. Send him to the wasteland. I think they should make an update to craft guns.

Comment: Mr. Handy only collects caps.

Comment: Also please don't include your own opinion in answers